# Custom attribute marking an API method for custom header values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building an API (lets call this one as `new api`) that behaves like an api-gateway to another Rest-API (lets call this one as `old api`).
In my `old api` i am checking request headers (`X-Some-Custom-Header` like so) and return response with respect to that header. Consider that header something like localization. 
I want to mark my `new api` methods with an attribute that so i dont need to specify every one of them like this :

```
[HttpGet({id})]
public IActionResult GetSomeValue([FromHeader] xSomeCustomHeader, int id){
    //some logical codes here
}
```

I know that there must be neat way to do this, obviously you can do a similar thing with `[Authorize()]` attribute.

By the way i dont need to use neither `Resources` nor configuring `RequestLocalizationOptions`. I just want to take that value and pass it to inner http request (im using `Refit` to call `old api`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible by writing your own **Model Binder** as described in [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to create a custom binder that maps parameters that are not in the **URL** path nor have an attribute to be extracted from headers.

**Update**

There might be a way to do it in refit as well by supllying a custom **IRequestBuilder** (the out-of-the-box implementation seems to be [RequestBuilderImplementation](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/master/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs)).

Once you have a custom implementation that suits your needs, you should be able to tell refit to use it through [RestService](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/master/Refit/RestService.cs)'s `For<T>(HttpClient client, IRequestBuilder<T> builder)` overload.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This actually helps me, but unfortunatelly i couldn't manage to pass that `custom-header` somewhere that i can actually access and add to my `Refit` headers.